# APA (7th ed.) citation/bibliography style with Springer template

Tags: biblatex, citing, overleaf

I wanted to add the citation (APA7) on the Springer template but I did not know how to do it on Latex (Overleaf). Do you have experience? Can you please explain?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Can you show us some tex code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners)

Comment: Have you checked out the official Overleaf resource regarding the topic? https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

The only LaTeX implementation for 7th edition APA style that I am aware of is the `biblatex`-based [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa).

There are lots of Springer templates out there and I cannot claim to have had a look at all of them, but the ones I looked at all used BibTeX/`thebibliography`-based bibliography solutions, which are completely incompatible with `biblatex`. Often the class loaded `natbib`, sometimes it loaded another package like `apacite`.

That means that you cannot really get 7th edition APA style with a Springer template.

For your submission I suggest you follow the author guidelines of your journal/book series as closely as possible while using the bibliography setup suggested in the template you are given. If any conflicts arise, contact the editor and ask for advice. Don't listen to random strangers on the internet.

Comment: +1, and haha for "Don't listen to random strangers on the internet."

Answer (score 0):

Though the official Springer-Nature template cannot directly provide APA 7 referencing style, it is quite easy to modify it to support APA 7 by using `biblatex`. The steps are as follows:

1. Choose any document class you like for reference style in the begining of the main tex file `sn-article.tex`. I prefer `\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}` since it's a provided APA style.
2. Open the file `sn-jnl.cls` and comment all the lines after `\if@APA@refstyle%` (related to the document class you choose in the first step) like this:

```
\if@APA@refstyle%
%\if@Numbered@refstyle%
%%  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}%
%  \gdef\NumBib{YES}%
%\else%
%%  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}%
%  \gdef\NumBib{NO}%
%\fi%
%  \bibliographystyle{apacite}%
%  \def\refdoi#1{\urlstyle{rm}\url{#1}}%
%  \renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}%
%  \AtBeginDocument{%
%    \renewcommand{\BPBI}{.}% Period between initials - command from apacite.sty
%  }%
%  \setlength{\bibsep}{1em}%
%  \def\bibfont{\reset@font\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\normalsize\selectfont}%
%\fi%
```

3. Add the following usepackages in the head of the main tex file `sn-article.tex`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sn-bibliography.bib}
```

4. Add `\printbibliography` at the end of the main body before `\end{document}` for printing bibliography and delete (or comment) `\bibliography{sn-bibliography}`.
5. Use `\parencite{label}` for `(name,year)` citation style and `\textcite{label}` for `name (year)` citationstyle.

The above steps work well in **overleaf** with the latest Tex Live version. If you edit your manuscript offline on your own PC/Mac, make sure your own Tex Live is the latest version as well.